# Scala: How to remove blank lines when reading text from file

Tags: scala, file, text

How can I ignore or remove blank lines, when reading from a text file using Scala?

An example is shown below: As you can see, the second line is the extra line.

> I. The Period
>
> It was the best of times,

Comment: Do you have any code to show us?

Comment: How do you read from the file?

Comment: Actually, I just do not have any idea of this.. The shown text is what I get after I using `val file = Source.fromFile(args(0)).getLines()`, but what I want is like _I. The Period It was the best of times,_ .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try this.

`val file = Source.fromFile(args(0)).getLines().filter(!_.isEmpty()).mkString(" ")`

It will remove empty lines from list of lines and then concatenate them into one string with space between lines.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to remove lines with whitespace only too. In that case this will work:

```
val file = Source.fromFile(args(0)).getLines().map(_.strip).filter(!_.isEmpty()).mkString(" ")
```